# CSS Allowed / Disallowed Characters

Tags: css

Is it possible to whitelist / blacklist certain characters in CSS ? For example, if I wanted to omit all non-alphanumeric characters from a block of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that is not possible in CSS. CSS is designed for layout/styling purposes only.

If you want to restrict characters you would need to use javascript or a server-side language, depending on where your content is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible.

CSS is a language which serves to define how a page is displayed. It is not intended to actually modify the content of elements. (Note that this is possible with the `content` property but with significant limitations. See http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/content for more information.)

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, CSS is a styling language. Try using javascript and pull out any non alpha numeric